# Linq how to Extend\Override existing toList() Method

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using Linq to Sql. I would like to open the transaction scope when I call (System.Linq) toList() method. Therefore, I was trying to override default toList() method by creating custom extension class and thereby creating new version of toList(). But within the custom toList() extension, I would like to call existing default (system.linq) ToList() method. But I am not able to do that. Please see the example below:

Code:

```
public static int GetRecordsWithNoChangeToQuery()
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventConn"].ConnectionString;
    using (var ctx = new EventsDataContext(connection))
    {
        var records = (from m in ctx.Event select m).ToList(); //calling custom extension method
        return records.Count();
    }
}
```

> LinqExtenionHeler

```
public static class LinqExtension
{
    public static TransactionScope CreateLockTransaction()
    {
        var options = new TransactionOptions
        {
            IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted
        };
        return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options);
    }

    //custom extension method
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> query)
    {
        using (TransactionScope ts = CreateLockTransaction())
        {
            return query.ToList(); //fails, not able to call system.linq .toList method
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code when I call query.ToList(), itsthrows error. As, it is trying to call itself.So how to call default (syste.linq) query.toList() from the same name custom extension method?

Comment: While you can do this, you should not.  You should give this method a different name, else it'll cause *way* more confusion than it'll add in value.

Comment: `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(query)` (but what Servy said)

Comment: Thanks Dennis. It works

Comment: Do you know as how to call .SingleorDefault() in above manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An extension method is just a fancy way to call a public static method. You can still call it the normal way and sometimes you have to.

```
 return System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(query);
```

However, I do support the comments that scream "wait, why are you doing this?". It seems like a suboptimal way to go about this. Maybe you should ask a more open question about your problem to get a better answer for your global problem, this is just fixing your local syntactical problem.

Comment: Actually I want to add Transaction support to legacy classes. So I do not want to change each every "linq to sql" query , thats why I am creating  a new version of toList(). Please let me know if you know of a better solution without massive code change?

Answer (score -1):

An extension method that you create for List , it will call internally to itself because type of query is **IEnumerable** and this will through exception or may be in deadlock condition.
so for ToList Extension method you can do one thing that passing parameter can be IQueryable.
So synatax as-

`public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)

{      using (TransactionScope ts = CreateNoLockTransaction())      {       return query.AsEnumerable().ToList();
  }
}`